# Synchronizing different database types across different servers

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, synchronization, unify

We are having difficulty keeping our data in sync.
We have been running a system on a UNIX machine for the last 20 years using a UNIFY Dataserver. There has been a push to move to Microsoft and are now also running a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 database on our Microsoft network. Certain tables from these 2 databases need to remain in sync. Additionally, the tables needing to be synchronized follow slightly different table structures.

The Microsoft SQL server runs on a 64bit machine. Unify have not written a 64 bit ODBC driver for us to use when trying to keep the databases in sync.

I have looked at the possibility of using database triggers on Unify which write logs of all changes made to the tables and then FTP the logs and apply the changes (or to call web services to apply the changes) , but when a trigger fires and writes a log/calls a service, if the transaction is rolled back the log still remains.

Does anybody have any ideas on what the best way to keep these databases in sync would be?

Thanks in advance

Grant

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into SQL Server Service Broker, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx

The best equivalent I can think of would be Oracle Streams if you have ever had the opportunity to use that.  A big concern though might be that you mentioned this Unify database not having ODBC driver support for 64 bit envioronments (All the more reason you should abandon Unify altogether).

Just keep in mind that despite claims the two will never truly be real-time in sync.  There will always be at least a slight delay.